# Efficient data pagination in SQL databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on optimizing a backend application where I need to implement pagination for large datasets in a SQL database. Traditional `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` methods are becoming inefficient as the dataset grows. What are more efficient ways to handle pagination in SQL for large datasets, ensuring both speed and scalability?

Additional details:

- Database: PostgreSQL
- Dataset size: Over 1 million rows

I have tried to implement standard pagination using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 10000 LIMIT 100;
```

I've observed increasing delays as `OFFSET` value gets larger.

What I'm looking for: alternatives to `OFFSET/LIMIT` for more efficient pagination.

Solutions that would allow faster querying, especially for data deep in the dataset.

Any implementation tips specific to [mention your SQL database, e.g., PostgreSQL, MySQL].

Expectations:

- Reduced query times for large datasets.
- Scalable approach for growing data.

Has anyone implemented an efficient pagination strategy for similar scenarios? I'm open to changing the query approach if it leads to significant performance improvements.

Comment: How quickly does your data change / how important are timely results? How often do you serve pages? If the data doesn't change often and there's many requests for the same page, caching may be a solution. Even if the cache only lasts a minute, in certain situations.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 0):

For large datasets, traditional pagination using OFFSET and LIMIT can indeed become inefficient because OFFSET still scans through all the rows before the starting point. A more efficient approach is to use "keyset pagination" (also known as "seek method"). Here's how you can implement it:

1. **Keyset Pagination:**
   This method relies on remembering the last item of the current page and starting the next page right after it. It avoids scanning through all previous rows, which increases efficiency.

   Example Query:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM your_table
   WHERE id > [last_id_from_previous_query]
   ORDER BY id
   LIMIT [page_size];
   ```

This method works best when the results are ordered by a unique, indexed column (like id in this example).

Considerations for Using Keyset Pagination:

It works well for forward scrolling but is less efficient for jumping to a specific page number.
Make sure the column used for ordering is indexed.
If the order is based on a non-unique column, you may need to use a combination of columns to maintain uniqueness.
Benefits:

Faster queries on large datasets.
Reduces load on the database as it avoids full table scans.
Drawbacks:

Not suitable for queries that require jumping to arbitrary page numbers.
Requires a unique, sequential identifier or a combination of columns that guarantee record order.
By using this method, you can significantly improve pagination performance on large datasets, making your application more scalable and responsive.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with large datasets in an SQL database, traditional OFFSET and LIMIT pagination can become inefficient, especially as the dataset grows. There are alternative approaches and techniques you can use to implement efficient pagination in PostgreSQL. Here are some suggestions:

```
1. Use Keyset Pagination
2.Cursor-Based Pagination
3.Materialized Views
4.Indexing
5.Caching
```

Comment: Those are good techniques. This would be a better answer with some explanation or references to such.